# BigQuery position function

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to use the position function and it doesn't seem to work as expected:

POSITION(field) - Returns the one-based, sequential position of field within a set of repeated fields.

I expect the position to give the original position in the data loaded, while I get the position in the result set (i.e - after the where clause ran).

Is there a way to get the position in the original data loaded?

Compare the two queries below to see the issue.

```
SELECT  
  ngram,
  cell.value,
  position(cell.volume_count) as pos,
FROM [publicdata:samples.trigrams] 
where ngram contains ", says Blake"

SELECT  
  ngram,
  cell.value,
  position(cell.volume_count) as pos,
FROM [publicdata:samples.trigrams] 
where ngram contains ", says Blake" and integer(cell.value) % 5 = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the position function gets evaluated after the where clause filters the nested values. You can fix this with a nested select:

```
select
  ngram,
  value,
  pos,
from (
  select  
    ngram,
    cell.value as value,
    position(cell.volume_count) as pos,
  from [publicdata:samples.trigrams] 
  where ngram contains ", says Blake"
)
where integer(cell.value) % 5 == 0
```

Comment: How do I get the position for a field nested in multiple level of records: select position(repeatedRec.rec1.field), where repeatedRec is a repeated record, and rec1 is a non-repeated record? Assume that repeatedRec doesn't have any other leaves.

Comment: A colleague of mine pointed out that flattening isn't actually being done by the where clause; instead, the issue is the ordering of operations; the where clause gets evaluated before the position function. To fix this, you can move the where clause to an outer select. I've updated my answer above; it should do what you expect.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to get the position of a field nested in 2 levels of records, where only the top most level is a repeated record?